# How do I override a JQuery (Datatable RowGroup) library function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm rather new to Javascript, and the scoping syntax definitely confuses me when looking at open source libraries especially when it has a lot of advanced concepts like closure, anonymous functions, etc. The [Jquery Datatables RowGroup](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/customRow.html) is a a bit [buggy](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46689/issues-with-rowgroup-responsive-combination) with Responsiveness, so I took the bold attempt of writing my own attempt at a solution.

Below is the relevant snippet from the [RowGroup library](https://github.com/DataTables/RowGroup), **source code from https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.1/js/dataTables.rowGroup.js**:

```
/** <Not sure what is going on here!> */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD
        define(['jquery', 'datatables.net'], function ($) {
            return factory($, window, document);
        });
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // CommonJS
        module.exports = function (root, $) {
            if (!root) {
                root = window;
            }

            if (!$ || !$.fn.dataTable) {
                $ = require('datatables.net')(root, $).$;
            }

            return factory($, root, root.document);
        };
    } else {
        // Browser
        factory(jQuery, window, document);
    }
}(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    /** </Not sure what is going on here!> */
    'use strict';
    var DataTable = $.fn.dataTable;

    var RowGroup = function (dt, opts) {
        //...
    };
    $.extend(RowGroup.prototype, {
        //...
        _constructor: function () {
            //...
            dt.on('responsive-resize.dt', function () {
                that._adjustColspan();
            });
        },

        /** I would like to override this function, externally */
        _adjustColspan: function () {
            @ @override
        }
    });
}));
```

Although it is [open source](https://datatables.net/license/), instead of modifying the library directly, I'd like to override the function *_adjustColspan* from a separate Javascript file (which will be included after this library). This will allow the library still be update-able without hassle, and any custom changes can be easily tracked.

**So first off, is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? If it is possible, how would I go about overriding this function in an external .js file?**

Edit:
It seems what I'm trying to do is coined "*Monkey patching*"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - please remember that this is not a general help forum, and it's not for these kind of general "please explain how everthing works" type of posts (see the policy article on [what is on-topic](/help/on-topic) for more information). If you don't know JS that well yet, even just answering question 1 is going to require first explaining quite a bit of JS basics, for which this is not the right website. The same goes for 2, and 3, to slightly lesser but still significant degree.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the link. I see, I will edit out 1. and 2. since they're not essential to the question I have. I don't believe 3. is off topic however, since it's just the main question I have, which is how I would generically monkey patch this specific java script library which is both a specific problem I have and the library is a software tool commonly used by programmers from the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Just to check: were these bugs ever filed over on https://github.com/DataTables/RowGroup/issues? Because that's how we all help get open source fixed for everbody, rather than writing a shim that only works for yourself.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not sure if this bug is currently under an open issue on their github, but I do believe this is a known issue, so I'm under the impression it'll be patched sooner or later. ["I'm afraid that Responsive does't currently play nicely with multiple rows in either the header for footer. That is something we are aware of and plan to address in future... so its not going to be available in the short term I'm afraid"](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/56927/datatables-net-with-rowspan-colspan-not-working-properly-for-large-tables).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans But in the meantime, I would of course need some short term solution. This is why I would like to not write to the library directly (monkey patch). So that when this does gets patched, and I update the library, it would be much more manageable than documenting where I had modified the library to a custom version that had suited my purposes.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans The purpose of my question is to find a good approach as a _short term_ workaround while waiting on bugs to be fixed. While this is a specific encounter, I'm hoping that the strategy I use here to fix it can be used again if I found another bug in a different library (whether the conclusion is that monkey patching is indeed possible here or if not, I would need to modify the library directly - but I guess that means I won't be able to do anything about bugs in non-open source libraries except wait?)

Comment: The code is on github, under MIT license, so you are perfectly allowed to fork the RowGroup extension repo, fix it, use your own fixed copy, and then if you want to be a good citizen of the open source web, file a PR with your fixes so that DataTables can make that available to everyone. However, if that's too much work (and hopefully it's not!) I've written up how to change that function "only for yourself". Which, again, is a far less nice solution. Forking and fixing is about as fast, but will allow for a better outcome for all.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans That's a very good suggestion. As someone who's new to the open source web, it's a little daunting to make my first contribution - because even though I have tested it for my particular case, I'm always afraid my changes will break core functionalities of other parts. 

That's why my current approach, I feel may be the practical way to continue developing my project without additional learning curve. But I definitely aim to build up the confidence and skill set to begin contributing to open source projects directly. I agree, that would be by far the best approach.

Comment: Everyone's first foray into open source is different, mine was "complaining to the people maintaining Processing.js until one of them convinced me I had the power to add what was missing". A few years later I owned the project. I'd wholly recommended at least trying the forking approach, and maybe talk about what you're doing in their forum, in case someone wants to help =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `RowGroup` object comes from an extension over on https://github.com/DataTables/RowGroup/blob/master/js/dataTables.rowGroup.js, which we can read through to see if there's some easy place we can grab a reference to it... and there is.

https://github.com/DataTables/RowGroup/blob/master/js/dataTables.rowGroup.js#L418 shows that its getting bound to `$.fn.dataTable.RowGroup`, which means that we can grab it from there in any context that has jQuery available.

```js
const RowGroup = $.fn.DataTable.RowGroup;

RowGroup.prototype._adjustColspan = function() {
  // do your own things here
}
```

(With the original code over on https://github.com/DataTables/RowGroup/blob/master/js/dataTables.rowGroup.js#L180-L184)

You can test this in your dev tools over on https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/styling/jqueryui.html, for instance. Typing `$.fn.DataTable.RowGroup.prototype` there gives us:

```
{​  
  _adjustColspan: function _adjustColspan()​
  _colspan: function _colspan()​
  _constructor: function _constructor()​
  _draw: function _draw()​
  _group: function _group(b, g)​
  _groupDisplay: function _groupDisplay(b, a)​
  _rowWrap: function _rowWrap(b, g, c)​
  constructor: function h(b, g)​
  dataSrc: function dataSrc(b)​
  disable: function disable()​
  enable: function enable(b)​
  <prototype>: Object { … }
}
```

And we can change that prototype to be whatever we want.